# Target an image/javascript link with Mechanize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-scraping, mechanize

I'm trying to use Mechanize to click a link with no text, only an image. The `href` is a Javascript function. Here's the link:

```
<a href='javascript:nextButton(this.form)'>
    <img src=./images/next.gif border=0 alt=Next width=20 height=20>
</a>
```

I'm using the sample code:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get(url)

next_page = agent.click(page.link_with(:text => /Sign In/)) # Change to??
```

But I don't know how to target something with no text. I'm guessing that I could either target the `img src` or the `alt` text, both of which are unique.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `.attributes['href']` on the `<a>`.